# Not able to add 'map.drawcoastline' to 3d figure using 'ax.add_collection3d(map.drawcoastlines())'

Tags: matplotlib, data-visualization, visualization, matplotlib-basemap

So I want to plot a `3d` map using `matplotlib basemap`. But an error message comes popping up.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap 
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection 
import numpy as np
map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-20,llcrnrlat=0,urcrnrlon=15,urcrnrlat=50,)
fig = plt.figure() 

ax = Axes3D(fig)
#ax.set_axis_off() 
ax.azim = 270 
ax.dist = 7
polys = [] 
for polygon in map.landpolygons: 
    polys.append(polygon.get_coords())


lc=PolyCollection(polys,edgecolor='black',facecolor='#DDDDDD',closed=False)
ax.add_collection3d(lc) 
ax.add_collection3d(map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25)) 
ax.add_collection3d(map.drawcountries(linewidth=0.35))
lons = np.array([-13.7, -10.8, -13.2, -96.8, -7.99, 7.5, -17.3, -3.7]) 
lats = np.array([9.6, 6.3, 8.5, 32.7, 12.5, 8.9, 14.7, 40.39]) 
cases = np.array([1971, 7069, 6073, 4, 6, 20, 1, 1]) 
deaths = np.array([1192, 2964, 1250, 1, 5, 8, 0, 0]) 
places = np.array(['Guinea', 'Liberia', 'Sierra Leone','United States','Mali','Nigeria', 'Senegal', 'Spain'])
x, y = map(lons, lats)
ax.bar3d(x, y, np.zeros(len(x)), 2, 2, deaths, color= 'r', alpha=0.8)
plt.show()
```

I got an error message on line 21{i.e  `ax.add_collection3d(map.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.25))`} saying:-

```
'It is not currently possible to manually set the aspect '
NotImplementedError: It is not currently possible to manually set the aspect on 3D axes'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this question because I had the exact question.

I later chanced upon some [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html) that revealed the workaround - if setting of aspect is not implemented, then let's not set it by setting fix_aspect to false:

`map = Basemap(fix_aspect=False)`

**EDIT**:

I suppose I should add a little more to my previous answer to make it a little easier to understand what to do.

The `NotImplementedError` is a deliberate addition by the matplotlib team, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1077/). What the error is saying is that we are trying to fix the aspect ratio of the plot, but this is not implemented in 3d plots.

This error occurs when using `mpl_toolkits.basemap()` with 3d plots as it sets `fix_aspect=True` by [default](https://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html).

Therefore, to do away with the `NotImplementedError`, one can consider adding `fix_aspect=False` when calling `mpl_toolkits.basemap()`. For example:

`map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-20,llcrnrlat=0,urcrnrlon=15,urcrnrlat=50,fix_aspect=False)`